# What is the intended way to create a Unicode character from concatenating variables?

Tags: rust

```
let mut start = true;
for v in count as String {
    s += match v as usize {
        n if n == 2 || n == 3 => "\u{00b" + n + "}",
        n if n >= 4 || (n <= 1 && !start) => "\u{207" + n + "}",
        start && 1 => "",
    }
    start = false;
}
```

I know this is not the intended way to write Unicode characters:

```
error: unterminated unicode escape (needed a `}`)
 --> src/main.rs:5:45
  |
5 |             n if n == 2 || n == 3 => "\u{00b" + n + "}",
  |                                             ^
```

But what is the right way?

Comment: You may want to try wrapping the offending pieces in `r#...#`, e.g. `r#"\u{00b"#`, i.e. mark them as [raw string literals](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine [`std::char::from_u32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/fn.from_u32.html) and [`String::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html?search=#method.push):

```
use std::char::from_u32;
let mut s = String::new();
s.push(from_u32(0xb0 + 2).unwrap());
s.push(from_u32(0xb0 + 3).unwrap());
s.push(from_u32(0x2070 + 1).unwrap());
println!("{:?}", s);
```